# Best way to pass an authorization function to another page with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm working with Google Calendar API for nodeJS and was able to authenticate using oauth2. The example is working correctly and displaying events from my calendar to the console. The token and credential JSON files are being stored in the same directory as the script I'm using.

My goal is to display those events that are on a single public calendar on a separate event's page. The events page is a public, static page written with HTML and has embedded JS in it. I would like to use NodeJS because I'm building the project with it currently.

I know there are a few ways to likely do this. As expected, events can be added and deleted at anytime, and I would want the events page to display the events list at the time the public user visits the static page. The code i'm using can be found in the Google API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: Please provide further info about the required behavior and the environment where this solution should work. As a first hint I would suggest to build a wrapper class around the API to hold authentication on a per user basis

Comment: @Newbie I just need a simple listing of the future events from a public calendar from Google. The NodeJS environment was set up because, along with express, I want it to handle my requests. I feel like keeping the function separate from the information displayed is ideal. I'm really just looking for the best way to handle exporting the results from the function without passing around the auth variable too much. again, forgive me if this doesn't answer the question; still VERY new to sever-side coding.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "exporting" or "passing" the auth variable (and also what you mean by "page") but what matters to googleapis at the end is that you eventually pass such auth on each API request. To repeat what Newbie said, one way to work around this is to have a class on the server-side that maintains the state of the relevant `auth` objects you need, then have that class execute the API calls with the appropriate auths.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply. @Crogo, Is this kind of what you're referencing? https://m.dotdev.co/how-to-use-classes-in-node-js-with-no-pre-compilers-and-why-you-should-ad9ffd63817d  The authorization and the function are in one js file that lives in a directory for api's. The information needs to be displayed on a separate event's page (HTML with embedded JS). I'm thinking I should assign the function to run on the page load of the event's page and then pass the response to the event's page?

Comment: No, the link provided by you talks about class inheritance (something more complex to do in JS, so I would avoid it). Please edit your question and explain your intended use, and how is your architecture going to look like. I'm mainly interested on how wil your users access this data (eg. Authentication or public) and how are you authenticating against Calendar API (where the required authentication media comes from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned two completely different things in your edit.

- The first link refers to a Node.js API which allows you to download events from a Calendar to a SERVER and interact with the Calendar to manipulate it.
- The second one lets you embed a Calendar in a web page. By using the second one you have no need for server-side code. Your CLIENT_ID and your API_KEY has to be provided publicly in the web page, but this is fine, they are meant to be used like this.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here we are talking about code architecture, so not many simple code snippets can be provided as a solution. First you need to figure out what is your system going to do from a conceptual point of view:

1. Is your 'website' (as we are talking about pages, but it may be an API as well) a broadcasting system. Hence it authenticates to 1 (or any number) of Google Calendars and provide its content to any user that gains access to it
2. OR your system will provide information from different Calendars to different users

Conceptually they are very different as in the first case your server should gain access to `n` Calendars and hold those keys available to any user, hence you may keep them in a variable that is available to any endpoint that needs that data. In the second you need to gain access to `k` Calendars for each user and handle a consistent binding between those.

In any case there shall not be major concerns of moving an `auth token` around within the same server as long as you are not accidentally sending it in any response.

Furthermore, I'm not quite sure which Calendar functions are you using, but I think the Calendar APIs are meant to be hit only few times and so you can not simply forward a Calendar API request each time a user hits a page where this data is going to be displayed, but rather; Authenticate to Calendar API, download the calendar data and preserve it locally, the use this data to generate your pages, then after some time refresh your local copy of the Calendar (this will work if your system is as per point 1 / but can be refined to work even for systems of type 2).

Comment: I have updated the question to answer those questions. Let me know if further clarification is needed. Again, appreciate the patience.

Comment: You mentioned two completely different things in your edit. The first link refers to a Node.js API which allows you to download events from a Calendar to a SERVER. The second one lets you embed a Calendar in a web page. By using the second one you have no need for server-side code. Your CLIENT_ID and your API_KEY has to be provided publicly in the web page, but this is fine, they are meant to be used like this.

Comment: This makes more sense. So, I shouldn't use NodeJS to handle the call to GoogleCalAPI to grab the events. NodeJS is better used with the Calendar API to store/manipulate/save changed data.

Comment: Need more help?

Comment: Thank you. I'm good. I have more confidence in learning API calls a bit better.